# jQuery click to scroll to cloest div.class and show not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi does anyone have any ideas what im doing wrong here?

When you click show content i want it to find the closest div with the class i ask and scroll to it but does not work... im new to jquery so maybe im doing wrong but i think my logic is correct haha

getting an error in console:

> Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show examples
  $(document).on("click", ".show-syntax", function(e) {
    var ele = $(this).parent().closest(".render-syntax");
    // this will search within the section
    ele.show();
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(ele).offset().top
    }, 100);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```css
.render-syntax {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="show-syntax">show content</a>
</div>

<div class="render-syntax">
  <p>content to show</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="show-syntax">show content</a>
</div>

<div class="render-syntax">
  <p>content to show</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="show-syntax">show content</a>
</div>

<div class="render-syntax">
  <p>content to show</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) doesn’t go through the siblings; [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) does the job you need. Simply replacing `closest` by `next` in your code will give you the proper behavior.

```
var ele = $(this).parent().next(".render-syntax");
```

Otherwise `ele` won’t have any elements, `ele.offset()` returns `null` and then there’s no `top` property of `null`, hence the error.

Comment: On someting else, do you know how i could have a button to copy the HTML thats inside the pre > code to clipboard? :)

Comment: @James Not sure which `pre > code` you’re referring to.

Comment: Oh sorry i have something else, i have example HTML in a documentation page that shows HTML markup inside <pre><code>.......</code></pre> and wondering if its easy to have a button that when clicked will copy the HTML example within that pre code :)

Comment: @James Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) help?

Comment: I guess i could replicate the HTML inside a textarea and hide it so it can be used to copy.... seems will be quickest and simplest way. Ill have a play. Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is NOT that ele.offset().top is undefined, it is that ele is undefined.

So I opened JS Fiddle, f***** it until it worked and now I can give you this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // show examples
    $(document).on("click", ".show-syntax", function (e) {
        var ele = $(this).parent().find(".render-syntax");
        // this will search within the section
        if (ele.css("display") == "none")
         {
    ele.show();
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(ele).offset().top
    }, 100);
    e.preventDefault();
             } else
                  {
                  ele.hide();
e.preventDefault();
                  }
  });

});
```

```css
.render-syntax {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <a href="#" class="show-syntax">show content</a>

    <div class="render-syntax">
        <p>content to show</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container"> <a href="#" class="show-syntax">show content</a>

    <div class="render-syntax">
        <p>content to show</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container"> <a href="#" class="show-syntax">show content</a>

    <div class="render-syntax">
        <p>content to show</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sorry for the poorly done JS {}'s, but JS Fiddle is just not my editor :D

Comment: There’s a `Tidy` button in the stack snippet editor _and_ in JSFiddle.

Comment: Does not work in the stackoverflow "Run this code snippet", but on JS Fiddle. Here is the Link: http://jsfiddle.net/8dvsadxo/

Comment: Thing is you moved the button inside the container, the container / content is outside of where the button is...

Comment: I do not see a problem in there, but if it will interfear with your design or whatever you can just use a unique ID to toggle, otherways use @Xufox' solution...